# To_CHAR result cannot go in VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is somthing strange I wouls like to understand

let's say we have this code :

```
DECLARE
a varchar2(6);

BEGIN
  a := '000001';
END;
```

This works good. No problem

Now we have this :

```
DECLARE
a varchar2(6);

BEGIN
  a := TO_CHAR(1, '000000');
END;
```

It does not work:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

why?

A problem with nls_language maybe?  what problem? what solution?

Thank you

Comment: `LTRIM` should do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `TO_CHAR` result has a space at the beginning, making its total length 7 characters. The space is reserved for a minus sign if the number is negative. If you try this query you'll see:

```
SELECT '[' || TO_CHAR(1, '000000') || ']' FROM DUAL;
```

The result is:

```
[ 000001]
 ^ space for a minus sign
```

To get the result without the space, use the `FM` modifier:

```
a := TO_CHAR(1, 'FM000000');
```

Comment: Incredible. I though I was crazy that `'0001' = TO_CHAR(1, '0000')` did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or, just use `LTRIM' :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    a VARCHAR2(6);
  3  BEGIN
  4    A := LTRIM(TO_CHAR(1, '000000'));
  5    dbms_output.put_line(a);
  6  END;
  7  /
000001

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that a leading blank only appears **before a positive number with no sign formatting. No leading blank appears before a negative number, or before any signed number, regardless of the placement of the sign.**
The ***“FM”* format** to **override the default leading blank for unsigned positive numbers**